QPrintPreviewDialog doesn't pass orientation to Windows print dialog
I'm running into a problem in setting the default print orientation using PyQt6. I set up a QPrintPreviewDialog attached to a QPrinter using this code:
printer = QPrinter(QPrinter.PrinterMode.HighResolution)
printer.setDocName('Bulletin')
printer.setPageSize(QPageSize(QPageSize.PageSizeId.Letter))
printer.setPageMargins(QMarginsF(0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25))
printer.setPageOrientation(QPageLayout.Orientation.Landscape)

print_preview_dialog = QPrintPreviewDialog(printer)
print_preview_dialog.paintRequested.connect(lambda: self.do_print(pdf_doc, printer, preview=True))
result = print_preview_dialog.exec()

When the preview dialog comes up, everything looks right. It is showing in landscape:

However, after clicking the print button, the Windows print dialog comes up and is defaulting to "Portrait":

I've been Googling around for a couple of days trying to find the solution, but I'm just not seeing anything, aside from general comments that calling setPageOrientation on the QPrinter should properly set the orientation.
FWIW, I also tried using just QPrintDialog called with that same QPrinter, and it still defaults to portrait.
How do I get that (second) print dialog to respect the orientation shown in the QPrintPreviewDialog?
FYI: Qt is version 6.7.0 and Windows is 23H2, build 22631.4541

Are you able to try with an earlier Qt version? The 6.7.* branch is known to have introduced changes that broke many aspects, and providing testing results against a <=6.6.* may help to find out if it's caused by that. That said, the QtPrintSupport related classes have been a bit "forgotten" in recent years: they're not a priority, as the Qt dev team has been too occupied with other aspects, ignoring important bugs or changes for that module that existed way before the further issues recent OS versions brought on (including Win11).

I'll give it a shot with an earlier version. I found a bit of a hacky work-around where using the win32print module I can change the printer's settings at the system level, but hopefully this can be worked out on the Qt side of things.

Unfortunately, it didn't work with 6.6.1. I may fiddle around with other versions if I don't hear anything else, or just go with setting it through win32print.

As said, the QtPrintSupport module has been left back a bit. It is possible that the issue is with the Win11 platform print support. If you can, consider a further shot with PyQt5 and see the result. Also: did you check the result of setting the page orientation of QPrinter and just calling related printing function, completely avoiding QPrintDialog and QPrintPreviewDialog classes? Furthermore: it seems you're trying to print a PDF document (which may have its own orientation), so you should consider providing a more comprehensive [mre].

Yes, I think that I'm just expecting too much out of QtPrintSupport. I did do this simply through setting the orientation of the QPrinter and calling the print function directly and it printed in portrait mode by default. I think the best way to do this is going to be to, already knowing the orientation of the PDF file, set that orientation through win32print then return the printer to its defaults when done. I'll make a post showing all of that in case someone else runs across this. Thanks for responding!

Ok, so it seems that neither QPrinter nor QPrintPreviewDialog passes landscape orientation on to the QPrintDialog. It seems, then, that the best way to get around this is to use the win32print module from pywin32 to set the orientation before calling the QPrintDialog, returning the printer to portrait orientation when done. Here's what is working:
import win32print
from PyQt6.QtPdf import QPdfDocument
from PyQt6.QtPrintSupport import QPrinter, QPrintDialog

"""
use win32print to access the printer at the system level and set 
the orientation there first
TODO: get the current orientation of the printer in case it's defaulting 
to a different orientation so that it doesn't get arbitrarily set to 
portrait afterwards
"""

defaults = { 'DesiredAccess': win32print.PRINTER_ALL_ACCESS }
printer_handle = win32print.OpenPrinter(win32print.GetDefaultPrinter(), defaults)
properties = win32print.GetPrinter(printer_handle, 2)
properties['pDevMode'].Orientation = 2
win32print.SetPrinter(printer_handle, 2, properties, 0)

*** create landscape pdf using ReportLab ***

pdf_doc = QPdfDocument(self)
pdf_doc.load(pdf_file_path)

printer = QPrinter(QPrinter.PrinterMode.HighResolution)
printer.setDocName('Bulletin')
printer.setPageSize(QPageSize(QPageSize.PageSizeId.Letter))
printer.setPageMargins(QMarginsF(0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25))
printer.setPageOrientation(QPageLayout.Orientation.Landscape)

print_dialog = QPrintDialog(printer)
result = print_dialog.exec()

if result == QPrintDialog.DialogCode.Accepted:
    self.do_print(pdf_doc, printer)

# set the printer's orientation back to portrait
properties['pDevMode'].Orientation = 1
win32print.SetPrinter(printer_handle, 2, properties, 0)
win32print.ClosePrinter(printer_handle)

def do_print(self, pdf_doc, printer):
    range_list = printer.pageRanges().toRangeList()
    pages_to_print = []
    if len(range_list) > 0:
        for i in range(len(range_list)):
            for j in range(range_list[i].from_, range_list[i].to + 1):
                pages_to_print.append(j - 1)
    else:
        for i in range(pdf_doc.pageCount()):
            pages_to_print.append(i)

    painter = QPainter(printer)
    do_new_page = False
    for page in pages_to_print:
        if do_new_page:
            printer.newPage()

        # orientation from the QPrintDialog is given back to the QPrinter 
        # instance and will be reflected in the pageRect
        page_rect_inch = printer.pageRect(QPrinter.Unit.Inch)
        dpi_x = printer.physicalDpiX()
        dpi_y = printer.physicalDpiY()
        rect = QRectF(
            page_rect_inch.x() * dpi_x,
            page_rect_inch.y() * dpi_y,
            page_rect_inch.width() * dpi_x,
            page_rect_inch.height() * dpi_y
        )
        render = pdf_doc.render(page, QSize(int(rect.width()), int(rect.height())))
        painter.drawImage(rect, render)
        do_new_page = True

